# create mysql query from a colum in a second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a piece of code that should get the names of food items that are not ingredients from one table and then generate a query to create another table with columns matching the names of those items this is not generating a table:

```
function create_table(){
$query = "SELECT * FROM food";
$tablequery = "CREATE TABLE (id int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,";
if($result=mysql_query($query)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if($result['ingredient'] != 1){
            $tablequery = $tablequery.$result['name']."varchar(30) NOT NULL,";
        }
    }
    $tablequery = $tablequery."PRIMARY KEY (id),UNIQUE id (id),KEY id_2 (id))";
}
mysql_query($tablequery);
```

}

I did call the function so that is not the problem and somehow it worked once but with just the id.

Comment: print the value of "$tablequery" and see whether the query formation is correct. Since, I could see that there should a space before "varchar(30)".

Comment: after printing I get CREATE TABLE Orders (id int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,Omelet varchar(30) NOT NULL,Peppers varchar(30) NOT NULL,Steak Sandwich varchar(30) NOT NULL,Chicken Quesadilla varchar(30) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id),UNIQUE id (id),KEY id_2 (id))

Comment: column names "Steak Sandwich" and "Chicken Quesadilla" has space.. check it out...

Comment: After the getting the valid query, try executing manually in db and then proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row['ingredient'] != 1){
        $tablequery = $tablequery.$row['name']."varchar(30) NOT NULL,";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add to your code a line to drop the table if it already exists:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `<your table>`;
```

Comment: table does not exist I am watching the database

Comment: so you need to name your table:
$tablequery = "CREATE TABLE '<your table>' (id int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,";

Comment: just found that one after printing it as mentioned above